# How to display a variable with double hashtags

Tags: coldfusion

I have a column in a data table that stores variables such as `#test#`. When I run a query I am displaying the column like this `#q_table.columnX#` which produces `#test#` on the screen. I want to be able to treat #test# as an actual variable instead of a display value.

Comment: #evaluate(q_table.columnX)#

Comment: @RobZ the evaluate worked fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use struct notation to display it.

```
#variables[q_table.columnX]#
```

Basically the above translates to

```
#variables['test']#
```

If you know the scope of the variable you're trying to pull this almost no reason you ever need to use `evaluate()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i didn't know the scope of the variable to be honest and I was getting errors for the java scope and stuff so I used evaluate().

Comment: plus one on evaluate. Nothing makes your code more complicated and since CF went to Java  (everything an object/scope) it's been unnecessary in almost all cases. It's an expensive tag under the hood using introspection. Not pretty :)